# How check if a word is in a list that is a key of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dictionary={('I', 'We', 'They'): 'X'}
```

For example I want to check is there `'I'` in this dictionary and if it is true, return `'X'`. Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you specify any code that you may have tried?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Why are you creating a `dict` like this?

Comment: First access the key in the dictionary, then check if the string exist in that key

Comment: @Asocia I want to translate a sentence through a dictionary which provides translation of four other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want more elements in your dictionary, so you will have to iterate over the keys of your dictionary and return when you found the right key. Like this:

```
def find_element(element):
    keys = dictionary.keys()
    for key in keys:
        if element in key:
            return dictionary[key]
```

You can call this function with "I" as element and you'll find the right value to your key.